# iAd campaign tracking disabled because the current date is past the campaign window

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

i have build an ios application objective c platform , i am trying to integrate google analytics to application . i have added these following code in my ios development.

// GAI options

```
GAI *gai = [GAI sharedInstance];
gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;

gai.logger.logLevel = kGAILogLevelVerbose;

[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;

// Creating the tracker.
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"My teacking id "];
```

but i got this kind of error on log

1)

> iAd campaign tracking disabled because the current date is past the
>   campaign window.

2)

> GGLClearcutLogger
>   sendNextPendingRequestWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke_3() Error
>   posting to Clearcut: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The
>   request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x134d4eda0 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.} 2016-08-31 19:19:16.228
>   InteractiveContacts2[649:135510] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.14
>   -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:223): Dispatch error: Error
>   Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x13657e6c0 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "The request timed out."
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://ssl.google-analytics.com/batch,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://ssl.google-analytics.com/batch,
>   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://ssl.google-analytics.com/batch,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://ssl.google-analytics.com/batch,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}

please help me out thanks in advance